# Adding CSS to react Component

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to add css to my newly created component. When I use inline styles it works. But when I try to import css from another separate file it doesn't work. Below I mention my 2 files.

**Layouts.css**

```css
.Content {
    margin-top: 16px;
}
```

**Layouts.js**

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import Auxillary from './../../hoc/Auxillary'
import classes from './Layouts.css'

const Layout = (props) => (
    <Auxillary>
        <div>
            Toolbar,Sidebar,Backdrop
        </div>
        <main className={classes.Content}>
           {props.children}
        </main>
    </Auxillary>
);
    
export default Layout;
```

Comment: How are you building your app? Static assets (like css) need to be run through an asset bundler like Webpack in order to use them. Alternatively, you can use jss or something like that

Comment: I don't think you need a named import just import './Layouts.css'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried making `className='Content'`

Comment: if it worked for you don't forget to mark it as a solution.  [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html) is a source for the solution also.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use classes.Content you must name your Layout css file like this

```
Layouts.module.css
```